Is this just asking me to see if these are a subspace?
Question that needs to be solved
For the odd problems I have no idea what to do.
For 7 I would try this approach.
I would say a + b + c = 2 then since the 0 vector cannot exist in it, then it means it also must not be closed by addition or multiplication, it must not be a subspace.
This problem though is specifically acting for the vector space, and it's making me confused if my even original approach is correct.
Does anyone know what this problem is asking, or if they can help me solve one of the examples so I can figure out the rest on my own.
Thank you.

You are right. Since the zero vector is not there, this can't be a subspace. Another way: note that the vectors $(2,0,0)$ and $(0,2,0)$ belong to the set, but their sum doesn't.

But is that what the problem is asking for? It says to 'use an appropriate theorem'. On this part I assume they mean: closed by addition/multiplication & 0 vector theories. 'to determine if the set W is a vector space' is a vector space the same thing as a subspace in this context is my question essentially.

Yes, looks like the problem asks to check if each of these sets is a vector space or not.

Well, they didn't write it in the best way. It's clear though that they mean the addition and scalar multiplication are the usual ones in $\mathbb{R^3}$. So checking if this is a vector space with respect to this operations is the same thing as checking that it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Okay thank you for the help, one more thing maybe that you can clear up is what does it mean if b,d are real. How does that change how I would solve the problem?

In $11$ they just mean all vectors of the form $(b-2d, 5+d, b+3d, d)$ where $b,d\in\mathbb{R}$. So it just means you go over all possible (real) values of $b,d$.
